# How do we get workgroup name from windows 10 in uwp?

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

How do we get workgroup name from windows 10 in uwp

and all other attribute of user?

Answer (score 1):

There is a User class available (UWP): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.user.aspx

There you can find the attributes of the user

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NetworkInformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br207293) class

For example to get computer name use:

```
var hostNames = NetworkInformation.GetHostNames();
var localName = hostNames.FirstOrDefault(name => name.DisplayName.Contains(".local"));
var computerName = localName.DisplayName.Replace(".local", "");
```

Or you can also use [ConnectionProfile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br207249) to get information about network.
Try something like this:

```
var result = NetworkInformation.GetConnectionProfiles();
foreach (var connectionProfile in result)
{
    foreach (var networkName in connectionProfile.GetNetworkNames())
    {
        // use networkName;
    }
}
```