# how to get group info(like guest,admin..etc) of current login user in uwp (windows 10)?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, xaml, win-universal-app

I want to get the Group name that belongs to current user in UWP(windows 10)?

i follow the links below:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.knownuserproperties.aspx

[Get UserName in a Windows 10 C# UWP Universal Windows app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33394019/get-username-in-a-windows-10-c-sharp-uwp-universal-windows-app)

But it does not help me find group name.

if it is possible in c# plz give suggestion or links..

Comment: [How do we get workgroup name from windows 10 in uwp?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36692062/how-do-we-get-workgroup-name-from-windows-10-in-uwp/36692606#36692606)

Comment: sorry alex i am not asking workgroup. I am asking for group belongs to current user like (Administrators,guest...). anyway thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0):

You can get user information from [User class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.user.aspx)

I am afraid that you can't get roles of user. UWP applications are sandboxed and system features are not available from them. If you need them you can create .Net application this way:

```
            // list all groups 
        foreach (var u in System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Groups)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} ", u.Value);
        }

        // check is user in group
        System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal principal = new System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal(System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent());

        if (principal.IsInRole(System.Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator))
        {
            // do what you want
        }
```

Comment: Thanks...can you give some easy link for .net application so that i can use it in brokered component.