# What is the best way to verify if a given username/password is a valid local administrator?

Tags: admin, uwp, credentials, verify

I have a UWP app that will be used by users that are not administrators on the machine.  I will be creating an admin page in our app that controls some settings for our app only.  I want to throw a username/password dialog that gates access to this admin page.  I only want administrators on the local machine to have access to this admin page, so I want to verify that the username/password given through my log-on prompt is a local admin on the box.  I don't need to "log" this user in anywhere, I just need to gate access to my admin page only to admin's on the box.

Can someone point me in the right direction?  I would rather use C# if possible.  A lot of the examples I have looked at appear to log the user in, I just need to verify the username/password are valid admin creds

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36713824/how-to-get-group-infolike-guest-admin-etc-of-current-login-user-in-uwp-windo

Answer (score 0):

UWP apps are sandboxed, so there is no info provided on user privileges level or system groups they belong to. Closest thing I could recommend is to store user name of first logged in user and then just check if currently authenticated user name and domain match stored values (so you will also avoid entering username/password and showing admin page/login to ordinary users).

```
IReadOnlyList<User> localAuthenticatedUsers = await User.FindAllAsync(UserType.LocalUser, UserAuthenticationStatus.LocallyAuthenticated);
User user = users.FirstOrDefault();
if (user != null)
{
    String[] userProperties = new String[]
    {
        KnownUserProperties.AccountName,
        KnownUserProperties.DomainName
    };

    IPropertySet values = await user.GetPropertiesAsync(desiredProperties);
    if (values[KnownUserProperties.AccountName] == storedAccountName && values[KnownUserProperties.DomainName] == storedDomainName) {
        ...
    }
}
```

However such approach does not allow to verify multiple admins on the same machine. As a work around you can maintain a list of approved users somewhere in your admin page/settings.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Interestingly, even though I am working on a UWP app - our app will never be submitted to the store, but sold directly to customers.  Therefore we don't need to abide by any of the store certification rules.  We this in mind - do you know of a way of achieving my goal of accessing the admin creds?

Comment: If you can write a desktop service that will check login/pass for you, than your UWP apps can communicate with such service.